# How to end PHP process if variable is blank/null

Tags: php, variables

I have a form submission page that POSTS the fields to a confirmation page that sends an email using PHP but I keep getting blank emails when the page is ran as a stand alone page instead of from the form submission page. The form has 'required', but I want to add a statement to the PHP that stops the process if the $email variable is blank/null.

```
<?php
    // variables start
    $team = $_POST['team'];
    $manager = $_POST['manager'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $classification = $_POST['classification'];
    $registration = $_POST['registration'];
    $division = $_POST['division'];
    // variables end

    // email start
    $subject = "Thank you for registering you team";    
    $message = "<html>...
```

In addition to stopping the process if the $email variable is blank/null, I also want to redirect the user to our home page.

Comment: Look at `if` statements with `empty`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php and for the redirect https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: `$team = $_POST['team'];` there is no reason to do this, you can use `$_POST['team']` anywhere you would use `$team` all you have done is double the memory used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
    // variables start
    $team = $_POST['team'];
    $manager = $_POST['manager'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $classification = $_POST['classification'];
    $registration = $_POST['registration'];
    $division = $_POST['division'];
    // variables end

    // email start
    $subject = 'Thank you for registering you team';
    $message = '<html>...';
} else {
    header('Location: https://example.com');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```php
...
// variables end

if( ! (!isset($email) || trim($email) === '') ){
  header("Location: homepage.php");
  exit();
}

// email start
...
```

Note the `exit()` statement after the redirection: without `exit()` or `die()` the PHP script could be continue the execution resulting in possible unexpected behaviour.